# Is this possible to stop the rerendering of child component when parent state updates

Tags: react-native

```
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <View style = {styles.calendarComponentView}>
              <CalendarComponent 
                selecteddate = {this.state.selecteddate}
                onChange = {this.onChange} />
            </View>

            <View style = {styles.timeSlotPagerView}>
              <TimingSlotPager 
                datasource = {this.state.datasource} 
                serviceSelected = {this.serviceSelected}
                currentPage = {this.state.currentPage}
                onPageChange = {this.updatePageIndex}
                {...this.props} />
            </View>
        </View>
```

I just want to re render only TimingSlotPager component not CalendarComponent when parent currentPage state changes.